# How does asp.net mvc convert post data to a model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

I am extracting some code from a project outside of the MVC-area to a HttpHandler while reusing as much code as possible.

To make things easy I would like to convert the posted data to the same Model that was already used in the Controller.

So, now I am looking for the logic MVC is using under the covers to magically convert posted data to a Model, but after several decompile attempts I am unable to find this.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

> SaphuA: Basically, I want to input the HttpContext and the type of the target Model and have the helper method do the rest of the mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Eric says, just extent the DefaultModelBinder.cs

The default model binder is [here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs)

The model binder is called from the [controller action invoker](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerActionInvoker.cs#L103)

The overall flow is nicely outlined [here](http://www.codethinked.com/ASPNET-MVC-Request-Flow) so just scroll to check where the controller action invoker is called.

If you want to spin up some unit tests around your implementation of the binder, check out the MVC source [tests](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/test/System.Web.Mvc.Test/Test/DefaultModelBinderTest.cs)

Using the github mirror because codeplex does not support line number linking yet :-)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I think [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/551576/ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-and-Data-Annotation) explains it pretty well.

In a nutshell there is a `DefaultModelBinder` class that handles the conversion of POST data into a model object.  You can even replace that model binder with your own if you like by extending it or implementing `IModelBinder` then registering your model binder with MVC in your Application_Start method.

Comment: Thanks. While informative, that post only seems to explain how to create a custom ModelBinder and manually map posted data. What I want to use is the magical one from MVC that does this automatically. Basically, I want to input the HttpContext and the type of the target Model and have the helper method do the rest of the mapping.

Comment: @SaphuA - In that case you could create a class that extends DefaultModelBinder and calls the base class methods to do the conversions.  You might need to mock up the ControllerContext and ModelBindingContext though.